# What is the transparent border around my Altium trace?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout

I am routing my first ever PCB and half way through the routing process I've noticed my tracks now have this transparent border around it. Any idea what this is ? I must have clicked something? Not sure how to disable it nor what it actually represents.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the clearance around tracks according to your current design rules. I.e. the space the trace you are currently routing can not enter. The shortcut is Ctrl+W (in Altium 21) and the preferences panel entry is called "Display Clearance Boundaries".